# Newman: send another request without waiting for the answer

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, newman

I am using Newman to send a list of requests: A B C D.

The problem is that the request C will take more than 10 seconds to response and I don't want to wait for it to finish before sending request D.

I've tried to use `setTimeout` in both **pre-request** and **test** of request C but it no use.

Are there anyway to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you provide more details about the request you created in Postman and the setTimeout you're created, please?

Comment: The flow is that I have to send request D while request C is still handling by the server. Otherwise the test case will always fail.